# How to duplicate a current record focused in oracle forms?

Tags: oracle, forms, plsql, oracleforms

I'm practicing oracle Forms, and I would like to know how I can to duplicate all values from a focused record. Do you have any idea? Thanks.

[image]
For example, I have actually my cursor focused in the record marked in yellow, I would like to click in "Duplicar" button (Duplicate in English) And then duplicate the actual record. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the option insert new record, this will create an empty row just beneath the record you selected.

Then click on the duplicate record button, this will duplicate all the values from the row above in the row you just created.

If you want to be this automatic you can write a Key-duprec trigger in which you put the following code:

```
insert_record;
duplicate_record;
```

Answer (score 1):

as much as i understand, you can perform these steps:

Firstly, you don't need to click on the duplicar button, use

```
WHEN-NEW-RECORD_INSTANCE trigger of comprobantes(master block).
```

In this trigger write this code:

```
declare
    v_detail_blk varchar2(99) :='detalles';
begin
    set_block_property(v_detail_blk,default_where,'cmp_no = '||:comprobantes.cmp_no);
    go_block(v_detail_blk);
    clear_block(no_validate);
    execute_query;
 end;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I think I've expressed wrong my question. I would like to create a new record using the same values focused in the current record. Is it possible? Thanks so much for reply!!!

Comment: @YoungAlCapone Use these properties : at item's "Property Palette" ( could be reached by selecting item and then pressing F4 ), - > "Data" - > "Synchronize with Item" or "Copy Value from Item"

Answer (score 0):

On the Duplicate button's when-button-pressed trigger you can call the built-ins create_record and then duplicate_record.  This will insert a copy of the record that current;y has focus.